# What does "in any other place the appearance of the wretched object would have occasioned a murmur of compassion" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The question is from a Nicholas Nickleby novel. What does this line mean?

> In any other place the appearance of the wretched object would have occasioned a murmur of compassion and remonstrance.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Nicholas Nickleby is quite difficult English!

Comment: Hello Abreeza and welcome to ELL! Could you please help us answer you by editing your question to tell us what you already understand? Is it the vocabulary? The sentence structure? What parts of it are already clear to you? What do you think it means? There's no sense in answerers telling you things you already know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question we need either more context or a link like [this](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Nicholas_Nickleby.djvu/153).

The "wretched object" is Smike.

The passage means:

> If Smike had appeared anywhere else, people would have murmured with
> pity [...and with complaint at the way he was treated.]

There is some ambiguity about the word 'appearance'. Smike *has* just appeared. **And** he looks (appears) wretched. Here Dickens probably wants us to understand *both* senses of the word.

The word 'wretched' means "in a very unhappy or unfortunate state." ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/wretched))

Referring to Smike as an "object" - something not human - may seem strange, but we often say, "Poor *thing*!" when sympathizing with someone.

The word 'occasion' is used *as a verb* only in formal English. It means "cause". Smike's appearance would have *caused* a murmur of pity...